# Use the fact $x \in A' \iff \forall r > 0 (B(x,r)\bigcap A \text{ is infinite })$ to show $(A \bigcup B)' \subseteq A' \bigcup B'$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Where $A'$ is the derived set. We note:

$$x \in A' \iff \forall r > 0 (B(x,r)\bigcap A \text{ is infinite })$$

Am I missing something here?

Suppose $x \in (A \bigcup B)'$. Then $\forall r > 0, B(x,r) \bigcap (A \bigcup B)$ contains infinite points of $A$ or $B$. This implies $B(x,r) \bigcap A$ is infinite or $B(x,r) \bigcap B$ is infinite. So $x \in A'$ or $a \in B'$. Thus $(A \bigcup B)' \subseteq A' \bigcup B'$.

Comment: How do you know that there aren't $r,s > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap A$ is finite and $B(x,s) \cap B$ is finite? (Once you know that you need to argue that, it's easy.)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the possibility exists since what I have so far shows these intersections must be infinite?

Comment: You know that $B(x,\rho) \cap (A\cup B)$ is infinite for all $\rho > 0$. If you have a family $\{ C(\rho) : \rho > 0\}$ of arbitrary sets such that $C(\rho) \cap (A\cup B)$ is always infinite, it can happen that you have a partition $(0,+\infty) = S\cup T$ such that $C(\rho) \cap A$ is finite for $\rho \in S$, and $C(\rho) \cap B$ is finite for $\rho \in T$. What's missing is the argument that this situation cannot happen when we have $C(\rho) = B(x,\rho)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong, because you need the same set ($A$ or $B$) for all $r > 0$. Now it could be that half of the time you'd have an infinite intersection of the ball with $A$, and another half of the time an infinite intersection with $B$, but not the same one for all $r$. In that case the proof would break down.

So to show the inclusion, we take any $x \in (A \cup B)'$. We have to show that $x \in A' \cup B'$. So suppose not: then $x \notin A'$, and $x \notin B'$.

By the property of infinite intersection, this means that there is some $r_1 > 0$ such that $B(x,r_1) \cap A$ is finite (as $ \notin A'$) and also some $r_2 > 0$ such that $B(x, r_2) \cap B$ is finite.

Now let $r = \min(r_1,r_2) > 0$. Now:

$$B(x, r) \cap (A \cup B) = (B(x,r) \cap A) \cup (B(x,r) \cap B) \subseteq (B(x,r_1) \cap A) \cup (B(x,r_2) \cap B)$$

and the right hand side is finite, as a union of two finite sets.

It follows, by the same property, that $x \notin (A \cup B)'$, which is a contradiction to how $x$ was chosen. So $x \in A' \cup B'$, as required.